# NodeJS + NGINX securing image files

Tags: node.js, nginx, jwt

I already configured nginx with nodejs and it's working perfectly as a reverse proxy, after that I put an authentication (username, password) in nginx to protect those photos from outside, how can i make a request to access those photos? I mean what request I need to create to authenticate input username and password? (WITH NGINX)

ps: I saw that would be nice to use jwt but I'm afraid to install openresty and lost my previous configuration of nginx.

What would be better? Configure jwt or try to authenticate with a user and pass in nginx?

Comment: if you're using HTTP Basic Authentication you can request it like: http://username:password@myserver.com/path/to/image

Comment: @MrWillihog Do you think is a good practice to store this password in a mobile app and then request it using username and pass, or is it secure?

Comment: I would say that is a totally different question. Without knowing how your application is setup and what size the user base will be it's hard to say. Basic Auth is ok for small things (as long as its over HTTPS), but for serving all static assets for a mobile app? I would say no.